# Are there any key binds to scroll between brushes?

Tags: sculpting, customization, sculpt-mode

I'm currently setting up a a sculpting preset for my TourBox and Blender, and while I understand the brushes have individual hotkeys I'm moreso looking for a "Next/Previous Brush" button so I can implement it into one of the dials on my TourBox, would anyone know if such a hotkey exists or can be configured?

Comment: You can create an [Operator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/operators.html) that goes through a defined list of brushes of your choice. The operator can then be triggered via a hotkey of your choice or by button press.